# Log nginx retry attempts \ count

Tags: nginx

We've configured retry using `proxy_next_upstream error timeout non_idempotent;` and it works great.

BUT  we want to be able to count how many retries do we have per request (or in total if nothing else).

How can we configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use configure your logs to print $[upstream_addr](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_addr) and count the times you have retry - i.e. multi ips in a request, as written in the documentation attached: `If several servers were contacted during request processing, their addresses are separated by commas, e.g. “192.168.1.1:80, 192.168.1.2:80, unix:/tmp/sock”.`
2. You can use use [nginx-amplify](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx-amplify/#what-is) , however I have never tried this and it is not all free...